# Get customer info on checkout registering after order is placed

Tags: php, magento, checkout

User comes to checkout and selects register as new customer, when placing the order, I am trying to get the info that he/she entered like:

```
//This is in Paypal Standard Model
$quote = $this->getQuote();
$isQuoteVirtual = $quote->getIsVirtual();
$address = $isQuoteVirtual ? $quote->getBillingAddress() : $quote->getShippingAddress();

//City:
$address->getCity();

//Country Code:
$address->getCountryId();
```

This works when the customer is logged in, but when he/she selects register this info is not available cause it is not saved in the sales_flat_quote_address table, is there a way for me to get customer info at this point? Any hook I can use or store it in the session or there is more elegant way of dealing with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: and by the way, I am using Magento 1.4.0.1 version

Comment: and where are you trying to get this info?

Comment: I have overwritten the Paypal Standard Model, with my own: class Zoran_Paypal_Model_Standard extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard and the method I am using this is: getStandardCheckoutFormFields() which executes right after the user places his/her order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to fix Paypal issue in Magento 1.4.0.1 version with this, but actually I found this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=8467 and the Magento Team is offering a patch for this if anyone find it useful: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/_media/patches/bug20832.patch